# Guzzle http не отправляет json запрос на сервер

Tags: php

Guzzlehttp 7.4

Воспроизведение проблемы:

> composer init composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle touch test.php

**test.php**

```
<?php    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();

$response = $client->post('http://localhost:8000/dump.php', [
    GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => ['foo' => 'bar'] // or 'json' => [...]
]);
```

> touch dump.php

**dump.php**

```
<?php
        ob_start();
        var_dump($_GET,$_POST);
        $output = ob_get_clean();
        file_put_contents('log.txt', $output,FILE_APPEND);
```

> php -S localhost:8000
>
> php test.php

**Ожидаемый результат** ([согласно документации](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json)):

Получить в log.txt json запрос отправленный методом POST

**Получаемый результат:**

1. Запрос приходит, и тип запроса правильный

   [Sat Nov 13 19:08:33 2021] PHP 7.4.3 Development Server (http://localhost:8000) started
   [Sat Nov 13 19:09:16 2021] 127.0.0.1:51972 Accepted
   [Sat Nov 13 19:09:16 2021] 127.0.0.1:51972 [200]: POST /dump.php
   [Sat Nov 13 19:09:16 2021] 127.0.0.1:51972 Closing

Но cat log.txt

```
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
```

Пустой, я не смог найти решение на сайтах, все из перечисленного не отправляет json в теле запроса. Можете сказать что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Считаю это отчасти потому что

> [Веб-сервер](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.webserver.php) предназначен для помощи в разработке приложений. Он также может быть полезным в тестовых целях или для демонстрации приложения, запускаемого в полностью контролируемом окружении. **Он не выполняет функции полноценного веб-сервера** и не должен использоваться в общедоступных сетях.

Вы можете использовать [php://input](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php) для получения содержимого запроса во встроенном (и других) сервере.

[Комментарий](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php#125651) говорит что $_POST используется для данных формы, в него нельзя передавать JSON/[XML](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php#114598). Подтвердил это, передав данные через form_params в Guzzle как массив - данные появились в $_POST. Для получения JSON используйте php://input.

Comment: на полноценном WEB сервере результат воспроизводится точно так же.